# Java - add a return statement

Tags: java, return

I am learning java so bear with me on this if it seems basic.  I have a method which I am trying to edit to return a value which is 'read in' - I am trying to return 'move'.  However, due to the setup of the code the return falls outside the code block and forces me to return a null.  Can someone edit the code so that it returns the 'move' value?  I have been working on this for 2 days and I can't work it out - the try and catch seem to be causing the problem

```
public Move listenToEngineMove()
{
  synchronized(engineReadBuffer)
  {
    int numRows=engineReadBuffer.size();

    if(numRows==0);

    for(int kk=0; kk<numRows; kk++)
    {
      String row=engineReadBuffer.get(kk);

      row=row.toLowerCase();

      if((row.contains("move "))||(row.contains(" ... ")))
        if((!row.contains("illegal"))&&(!row.contains("error")))
          try { 
            String[] tokens=row.replaceAll("\\<.*\\>"," ").split("\\s+");
            Move move = new Move(tokens[tokens.length-1]);
            jcb.makeAIsMove(move);

            System.out.println("thread.... " + row);
          }  
          catch (Exception x) {
            System.out.println("Exception! : "+x.getMessage());
          } 
    }

    engineReadBuffer.clear();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: *"I am learning java ..."* - One of the things you need to learn is to indent your code consistently.

Comment: There's no evidence of you *trying* to return `move` - what have you tried, and did the obvious `return move;` not work?

Comment: As @StephenC says. Once you format it correctly - you'll see where the return goes. Have  look a this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/10-best-practices-code

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
public Move listenToEngineMove() {
    Move move = null;
    synchronized (engineReadBuffer) {
        int numRows = engineReadBuffer.size();
        if (numRows == 0) ;   // what on earth is this?
        for (int kk = 0; kk < numRows; kk++) {
            String row = engineReadBuffer.get(kk);
            row = row.toLowerCase();
            if ((row.contains("move ")) || (row.contains(" ... ")))
                if ((!row.contains("illegal")) && (!row.contains("error")))
                    try {
                        String[] tokens = row.replaceAll("\\<.*\\>", " ").split("\\s+");
                        move = new Move(tokens[tokens.length - 1]);
                        jcb.makeAIsMove(move);

                        System.out.println("thread.... " + row);
                    } catch (Exception x) {
                        System.out.println("Exception! : " + x.getMessage());
                    }
        }
        engineReadBuffer.clear();
    }
    return move;
}
```

I'd recommend that you replace this:

```
catch(Exception x){System.out.println("Exception! : "+x.getMessage());}
```

with this:

```
catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();   // Or, better yet, logging with Log4J
}
```

The complete stack trace gives more info than the message.

This line looks like a mistake to me.  The semi-colon at the end looks out of place.

```
if (numRows == 0) ;   // what on earth is this?
```

Your code looks awful.  I find it hard to read, because you aren't consistent with your indentation and general code style.  Style matters; it makes your code easier to read and understand.  Adopt a better style and stick with it.

Comment: How so?  What would you have changed?  Do you mean reformatting the code?  Done.

Comment: This won't work, the return statement is outside the block that declared `move`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to **move 'Move' just inside synchronized block,** It is important to keep it inside synchronized block to stay thread safe.

```
public Move listenToEngineMove()
{
synchronized(engineReadBuffer)
  {
      Move move =null;

      int numRows=engineReadBuffer.size();
      if(numRows==0);

   for(int kk=0; kk<numRows; kk++)
     {
     String row=engineReadBuffer.get(kk);
     row=row.toLowerCase();

     if((row.contains("move "))||(row.contains(" ... ")))
      if((!row.contains("illegal"))&&(!row.contains("error")))
       try { 
        String[] tokens=row.replaceAll("\\<.*\\>"," ").split("\\s+");
        move = new Move(tokens[tokens.length-1]);

             System.out.println("thread.... " + row);
            }  
       catch(Exception x){System.out.println("Exception! : "+x.getMessage());} 
     }  
   engineReadBuffer.clear();
   return move;//this is inside synchronized block
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Return statement now working correctly and comments taken on board re code formatting and consistency